# Does phx.server in detached mode start automatically?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

When you execute

```
MIX_ENV=prod PORT=4001 elixir --erl "-detached" -S mix phx.server
```

on a VPS server's terminal. Does restarting the VPS server

close the phx.server?

Comment: as a warning `--detached` is considered deprecated. If this is your release you should use `mix release`.

Comment: Why did the official documentation say use --detached?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you start the process in the OS, restarting the VPS server would shut it down. Basically, restarting the OS kills all the processes.

To make the process start with the OS, one should use OS tools. Most modern Linux distros use [`systemd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) for this purpose (legacy *Ubuntu* was using [`upstart`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/).)

To make the process restart one should provide the `service` configuration file and *enable* the service for restarts on the target machine.

Comment: Can you point me to a good tutorial so I can run phx.server in systemd?

Comment: I never read tutorials so I am not aware of any “good one.” `man systemd` is very detailed.